# Sci fi book series about two boys, one from the modern day, one from the future, who swap places. Set in the UK

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

- The boy from the future has an AI assistant.  When he turned 10 (or 12) he was given a choice between an AI that had opinions or one that just did whatever you told it to do.  He was lazy and preferred one that could think for itself, whereas his peers all picked the subservient type of AI.
- in the second book, the boy from the future is trying to get into town and reconfigured a lawn mower.
- it was a series of books
- I read this in the mid 90's

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's possible this is [Kappatoo by Ben Steed from 1989](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kappatoo).

I only know it from the TV series, but that was based on the book. As far as I'm aware, there was only one book, but there were 2 seasons of the show.

A young teenager from the future time travels to swap with someone who looks exactly like him, and hijinks ensue.

The present-day part is set in a school in 1990, and the future is just weird future stuff that was common on TV in those days.

There is an "AI assistant" in the form of a computer which appeared as a human.

Comment: If so _Kappatoo_ is the boy from the future and _Simon_ is the boy from the current time. There were two books in the series. There is some info on the second book [A Stitch in Time](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/25899619-kappatoo) on Goodreads.

Comment: This is it!  Thank you!